# css-equivalent of jQuery's $(...).css(prop, '')?

Tags: css

With jQuery one can *rescind* an earlier CSS setting by passing an empty string as the "setting." 
 E.g. After something like:

```
$('#foo').css('display', 'none');
```

...the expression:

```
$('#foo').css('display', '');
```

will essentially *cancel* the earlier setting.

Is there an analogous way to *cancel* an earlier setting in CSS?

For example, suppose I set some CSS property for an element `X`, how can I specify the *unsetting* of this same property in an `X:hover` directive?

Comment: define #X:hover{  } in css with intended "removals". should work for you

Comment: `display: initial` or `display: inherit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property to a default value (which may be "inherit").  This is probably more looking up what default values you're using, and organization, than you're asking for.

```
X { outline: 1px solid red; }
X:hover { outline: none; }
/* this is different than not setting { outline: 1px solid red; } on X:hover! */
```

Or you can not select X:hover when setting it in the first place.

```
X:not(:hover) { outline: 1px solid red; }
```